lttng-modules-dkms Install Error
I'm trying to install a ros2 tracing tool (https://github.com/ros2/ros2_tracing/tree/humble). One of the requirements to get this package to work is to install the lttng-modules-dkms package.
However, I'm encountering the following issue after running sudo apt-get install lttng-modules-dkms 
Reading state information... Done
lttng-modules-dkms is already the newest version (2.13.8-1~ubuntu22.04.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up lttng-modules-dkms (2.13.8-1~ubuntu22.04.0) ...
Removing old lttng-modules-2.13.8 DKMS files...
Deleting module lttng-modules-2.13.8 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new lttng-modules-2.13.8 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 6.5.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/lttng-modules-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-34-generic (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package lttng-modules-dkms (--configure):
 installed lttng-modules-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lttng-modules-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Does anyone know why this is happening/how I can resolve this? I'm entirely sure what exactly the error is.
Machine Information: Mac M1 running a VM via UTM (Ubuntu 22.04 aarch64)
Additionally, the log at /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/make.log has the following information:
Mon May 13 12:33:12 AM EDT 2024
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-34-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client-discard.o
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/Kbuild:27: File ./mm/slab.h not found. Probe "kmem" is disabled. Use full kernel source tree to enable it.
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/Kbuild:187: Files ./fs/btrfs/*.h not found. Probe "btrfs" is disabled. Use full kernel source tree to enable it.
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/Kbuild:206: Files ./mm/internal.h not found. Probe "compaction" is disabled. Use full kernel source tree to enable it.
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/Kbuild:215: Files ./fs/ext4/*.h not found. Probe "ext4" is disabled. Use full kernel source tree to enable it.
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/Kbuild:244: File ./drivers/base/regmap/trace.h not found. Probe "regmap" is disabled. Need Linux 4.1+ kernel source tree to enable it.
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-sched.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_backend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/tests/probes/lttng-test.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:16,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client-discard.c:16:
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/../include/lttng/events-internal.h:292:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uuid_le\u2019
  292 |         uuid_le uuid;                   /* Trace session unique ID (copy) */
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/../include/lttng/events-internal.h:466:9: error: unknown type name \u2018uuid_le\u2019
  466 |         uuid_le uuid;                           /* Trace session unique ID */
      |         ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/string.h:294,
                 from ./include/linux/bitmap.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/cpumask.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/smp.h:13,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_timer.h:18,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/timex.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from ./include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/stat.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client-discard.c:10:
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h: In function \u2018client_buffer_begin\u2019:
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:361:49: error: request for member \u2018b\u2019 in something not a structure or union
  361 |         memcpy(header->uuid, session->priv->uuid.b, sizeof(session->priv->uuid));
      |                                                 ^
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:638:34: note: in definition of macro \u2018__fortify_memcpy_chk\u2019
  638 |         const size_t __q_size = (q_size);                               \
      |                                  ^~~~~~
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:694:35: note: in expansion of macro \u2018__struct_size\u2019
  694 |                 __struct_size(p), __struct_size(q),                     \
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:361:9: note: in expansion of macro \u2018memcpy\u2019
  361 |         memcpy(header->uuid, session->priv->uuid.b, sizeof(session->priv->uuid));
      |         ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:361:49: error: request for member \u2018b\u2019 in something not a structure or union
  361 |         memcpy(header->uuid, session->priv->uuid.b, sizeof(session->priv->uuid));
      |                                                 ^
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:640:40: note: in definition of macro \u2018__fortify_memcpy_chk\u2019
  640 |         const size_t __q_size_field = (q_size_field);                   \
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:695:35: note: in expansion of macro \u2018__member_size\u2019
  695 |                 __member_size(p), __member_size(q),                     \
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:361:9: note: in expansion of macro \u2018memcpy\u2019
  361 |         memcpy(header->uuid, session->priv->uuid.b, sizeof(session->priv->uuid));
      |         ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:361:49: error: request for member \u2018b\u2019 in something not a structure or union
  361 |         memcpy(header->uuid, session->priv->uuid.b, sizeof(session->priv->uuid));
      |                                                 ^
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:648:30: note: in definition of macro \u2018__fortify_memcpy_chk\u2019
  648 |         __underlying_##op(p, q, __fortify_size);                        \
      |                              ^
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client.h:361:9: note: in expansion of macro \u2018memcpy\u2019
  361 |         memcpy(header->uuid, session->priv->uuid.b, sizeof(session->priv->uuid));
      |         ^~~~~~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lttng-ring-buffer-client-discard.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/tests/clock-plugin/lttng-clock-plugin-test.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/tests/lttng-test.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_frontend.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/tests/lttng-clock-plugin-test.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_iterator.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-irq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_vfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_splice.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-timer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_mmap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/prio_heap/lttng_prio_heap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/../wrapper/splice.o
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_mmap.c: In function \u2018lib_ring_buffer_mmap_buf\u2019:
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_mmap.c:116:23: error: assignment of read-only member \u2018vm_flags\u2019
  116 |         vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTEXPAND;
      |                       ^~
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib/ringbuffer/ring_buffer_mmap.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-module.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-power.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-statedump.o
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:488: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/lib] Error 2
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-9p.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-i2c.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-kvm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-signal.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-block.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-napi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-skb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-net.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/../../include/lttng/define_trace.h:87,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/../../include/instrumentation/events/skb.h:92,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-skb.c:29:
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/../../include/lttng/tracepoint-event-impl.h:133:6: error: conflicting types for \u2018trace_consume_skb\u2019; have \u2018void(struct sk_buff *)\u2019
  133 | void trace_##_name(_proto);
      |      ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/../../include/lttng/tracepoint-event-impl.h:45:9: note: in expansion of macro \u2018LTTNG_TRACEPOINT_EVENT_INSTANCE_MAP\u2019
   45 |         LTTNG_TRACEPOINT_EVENT_INSTANCE_MAP(map, name, map, PARAMS(proto), PARAMS(args))
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/../../include/instrumentation/events/skb.h:64:1: note: in expansion of macro \u2018LTTNG_TRACEPOINT_EVENT_MAP\u2019
   64 | LTTNG_TRACEPOINT_EVENT_MAP(consume_skb,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/trace/events/skb.h:10,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-skb.c:18:
./include/linux/tracepoint.h:255:28: note: previous definition of \u2018trace_consume_skb\u2019 with type \u2018void(struct sk_buff *, void *)\u2019
  255 |         static inline void trace_##name(proto)                          \
      |                            ^~~~~~
./include/linux/tracepoint.h:432:9: note: in expansion of macro \u2018__DECLARE_TRACE\u2019
  432 |         __DECLARE_TRACE(name, PARAMS(proto), PARAMS(args),              \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/tracepoint.h:566:9: note: in expansion of macro \u2018DECLARE_TRACE\u2019
  566 |         DECLARE_TRACE(name, PARAMS(proto), PARAMS(args))
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/trace/events/skb.h:54:1: note: in expansion of macro \u2018TRACE_EVENT\u2019
   54 | TRACE_EVENT(consume_skb,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes/lttng-probe-skb.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:488: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src/probes] Error 2
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:488: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build/src] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-34-generic/Makefile:2039: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.13.8/build] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-34-generic'


I encounter a nearly identical error on x86_64 architecture. Oren's answer worked.

I got the same error, but when I install from their stable PPA (as opposed to the default packages), it works fine.
Summary:
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lttng/stable-2.13
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lttng-tools lttng-modules-dkms liblttng-ust-dev

